# Ubuntu gone out of order - Wont install any packages. What do I do?

Tags: updates, software-center, package-management, software-installation

Lately, I've been getting some strange behaviour from Ubuntu. First and the most important is that  it wont install updates. It gives a package installation error and it simply wont work.

Earlier I tried to install TeamViewer via the Software Center, but got the same package error. I also feel like the connection speed is going slower than it should - don't know if this one is relevant to this case.

What's wrong with my installation? How do I fix these package installation errors?

[image]

Comment: What errors? post error-code or screen-shot.

Comment: Added a screenshot.

Comment: Can you install from the command line? This will better help us determine what's gone wrong.

Comment: @Aborted - please run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` - copy and paste the output you see in the terminal to paste.ubuntu.com - this will allow everyone to see the exact error causing your issue.

Comment: Can you show the content of file    /var/log/apt/history.log

Comment: @Aborted Open a terminal with CTRL-ALT-T and provide the information fossfreedom requested by running the command that he provided. Please help us help you! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is a very common recurring Ubuntu question.  It's asked in many different ways.  However, the answer is always the same.  I run into the problem often when having broken packages.  I review this link:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/461975/i-cant-edit-update-remove-or-install-my-broken-packages

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
$ sudo apt-get --purge remove && sudo apt-get autoclean
$ sudo apt-get -f install
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

You performed most of them.  There are still a couple more that can be added.  But so far the ones in the list has fixed my corrupted Ubuntu broken package problems.

As far as Teamviewer installation you have after you have fixed the broken package problem try this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0
$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
$ sudo apt-get update
## (Download the latest 32-Bit / 64-Bit Multiarch go to the download and run)
$ sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_linux.deb
```

Comment: This didn't work unfortunately. I think your solution kinda made my system worse.

Comment: @Aborted which part made the system worse, the first half of the answer should fix any "fixable" apt/dpkg corruption, if this made it worse that would mean a very large corruption in the package management system or another issue entirely (but even then an apt/dpkg reset should not have hurt). Regardless, it is very difficult to debug a problem with only a graphical error message and description, please post logs all the commands you have run and their outputs as suggested in many comments if you want better help from the community.

Comment: @Aborted I would also like to add, that I am not trying to be abrupt or rude, I understand you are frustrated, I have been in that position many times. But when you are asking for help from anyone, it is best to take the time to [phrase your question in a way that someone else can answer](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx). I often find that more often than not, in the process of preparing a question I find the solution myself just from the preliminary research and evidence gathering.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a similar problem I was having with a kernel earlier today. I came across [this site](http://iasptk.com/ubuntu-fix-broken-package-best-solution/) which actually fixed it. I had to manually fix it by editing the dpkg status file.

But before doing any of this make a backup of the original **status** file so you can revert back to it if this does not fix it.

1. `sudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status`
2. `Then locate the corrupted package. Remove the whole block of information pertaining to it, save then exit.`

If you dont know which package is causing this you could run:

> sudo apt-get update
>   sudo apt-get upgrade

and that may tell you which packages you are having troubles with, e.g.

> Errors were encountered while processing
>   /var/cache/apt/archives/ (package name here)
>   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I really cant tell because I dont know what error messages you are getting within the terminal. But if that sounds like it may help, it would be worth the try. Plus if it does not you could always restore the backed up file. One thing, I would not reboot until I knew if it worked or not. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance that `/boot` partition is full and in that way, installation and update will fail.

To check if that partition is full, open a terminal and type the command `df` and it will show something like:

```
Filesystem              1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntu-root 959421896 379475996 531218164  42% /
udev                       832664         4    832660   1% /dev
tmpfs                      168352       576    167776   1% /run
none                         5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock
none                       841752         0    841752   0% /run/shm
cgroup                     841752         0    841752   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                  233191     27581    193169  13% /boot   <==== Note this line
```

If Use% for `/boot` is like 99% you will need to clear old package backups.  Check what is in your folder `/boot` with the command `ls /boot`.  If you are seeing a lot of files like `initrd.img-3.2.0-##-generic` `vmlinuz-3.2.0-##-generic` (where ## are version numbers like 40, 41, 42, 43 and you may find like tens of copies) it is actually safe to remove some old copies.

Use the command to remove old copies:

```
dpkg --get-selections|grep 'linux-image*'|awk '{print $1}'|egrep -v "linux-image-$(uname -r)|linux-image-generic" |while read n;do sudo apt-get -y remove $n;done
```

(Credit to [this link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1435818), modified to make it work in ubuntu)

Then run `sudo apt-get autoremove` to clean up dependencies.

Comment: While this is certainly a useful answer, many ubuntu users do not use a separate boot partition, the default partitioning scheme has a flat filesystem for / and a separate swap partition.